# SCIM Wso2is performance

Tags: performance, wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2IS version 5.3 with MySQL using mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin driver and DB Size of 220K users . when using SCIM to change the attributes for a user takes ~ 4.6 secs versus reading/creating a user takes ~ 1.1 sec. Any Suggestion for lowering those times?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look WSO2 SCIM reference architecture from [1]. There you can see 
SCIM user manager which is a wrapper of Carbon user manager and WSO2 Charon which is responsible for decoding SCIM request and encoding SCIM response. There are three level of bottle neck can happen

Level 01: Charon SCIM request and response, decoding and encoding 
Level 02: How SCIM user manager utilize Carbon user manager functions to do user store operations 
Level 03: Actual user store operations need to with underlaying user store.

Some of tips to isolate performance issue

1. Do user update operation from management console and check latency if same latency is there issue is with underlaying user store
2. Disable user store operation event listeners from identity.xml

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+SCIM+Service+Provider

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Gayan's tips to isolate the performance issue.

You can [enable JDBC logging with log4jdbc](http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2016/07/how-to-use-log4jdbc-with-wso2-products_28.html) and monitor the time taken to execute each DB query. Then you may be able to narrow down the issue, whether it is in the DB interaction or not.

Comment: Any other Performace logging for example for network portion of JDBC